# How to reduce nodes using Hbase-Indexer-mr

Tags: hadoop, solr, mapreduce

I have a question about how to reduce nodes when I am running hbase-indexer-mr-*-job.jar.

I am using Cloudera Manager 5.2

Basically, I have 9 servers. cys-master, cys-slave1, cys-slave2, cys-slave3, cys-slave4, cys-slave5, cys-slave6, cys-slave7, cys-slave8.

Hbase tables are stored in these 9 servers.
However, I only installed Solr in cys-master, cys-slave1, cys-slave2, cys-slave3, cys-slave4.

In cys-master, when I ran

```
hadoop jar hbase-indexer-mr-*-job.jar 
--hbase-indexer-zk localhost 
--hbase-indexer-name myindexer 
--reducers 0
```

There are about 15 map tasks in hadoop.

cys-slave1, cys-slave2, cys-slave3 and cys-slave4 could successfully upload indexers to Solr.
cys-slave5, cys-slave6, cys-slave7, cys-slave8 got error messages: "Connection refused". The whole process will fail eventually.

My question is: How could I exclude cys-slave5, cys-slave6, cys-slave7 and cys-slave8?